# Win 7 - How to customize window colors?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

Is it possible to customize ALL possible colors in Win 7? The same way we did it in Win XP?
Because I would like a darker color for applications (for example the panel where you write your text in Notepad is pure white now, I would like it a bit gray).

The [documentation](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/282-window-color-appearance-change.html) I have found tells that the colors can be changed only if the user switches to classic Windows style. Microsoft's web site also tells nothing about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done. Period.
Maybe in the next version of Windows.

Comment: Maybe in the **previous** version of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing has changed much, except the packaging. Whatever you could do in XP you can still do in 7, with some new theme options that didn't exist in XP.

See : [How to Change the Window Color and Appearance in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/282-window-color-appearance-change.html).

Comment: I know that page already. But it is not helping. If you read section 7, you will see that you have to disable themes (switch to Win 98 classic interface) in order to be able to change ALL colors.

Comment: And here is a exact quote from section 7: "If any other theme is applied, you will not be able to change colors and sizes for items"

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to customize ALL colors in Windows 7 as you did in Windows XP. As it was stated in harrymc's link, under step 7, it says:

**WARNING: Colors and sizes selected for items will only be used if you have selected a Windows Classic or High Contrast theme. If any other theme is applied, you will not be able to change colors and sizes for items.**

There is currently no support to change ALL colors in Windows 7.

Comment: I have found the same documentation and I have seen that using that approach it cannot be done. This is why I was asking here. I hoped that it is another way to do it.

Comment: That's basically your answer, you can't do it. No way, not even with hacks.